# VBA Excel : run-time error -2127417848 automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its client

Tags: vba, forms, excel

Backstory and pertinent info:

I am not a professional coder. I used to do Oracle pl/sql a long, long, long time ago. Back then I would tinker with VB, I am by no means an expert. As far as Excel, this is my first attempt at using macros. I created this file/form so that myself and others can track issues/trends over time.

This is a spreadsheet sitting on a network drive that many users will access. It has a macro data entry form that will open automatically when the file is opened. Also, the form can be manually opened (Ctrl+Shift+H) if the user happens to close the form without closing the file.

The file was created using Excel 2010 and all users machines are running Excel 2010. All machines are Running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.
All users can open and add/edit the file...except one (the main user that will use this form the most!) **Note: The machine in question has no issues opening ANY other Excel file...just this one.

When the spreadsheet is opened, it is protected so that if the form is closed, the data cannot be accidentally deleted. Within the code right before the insert it is unprotected, activated, then inserted. After the insert it is protected again.

There are two main errors.

1. When clicking on the File itself from Explorer, Excel hangs, crashes, and attempts a restart.
2. When opening Excel and clicking on repair the file, the spreadsheet will open, the form will show. The user will enter the data, Click the "Record Entry" button. The data is not inserted and the following message appears:

> "run-time error -2127417848 automation error the object invoked has
>   disconnected from its client"

Things that I have tried with no success (from ideas brought forth with other similar problems):

I have added a blank module, added the “Activate” verbiage, and run the compatibility troubleshooter, with no success.

I have supplied the code for the following:

Microsoft Excel Objects : ThisWorkBook

Forms : usrfrm_HC

Modules : Module1 and Module2

---

ThisWorkBook Code:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = ActiveSheet 
    ThisWorkbook.Activate 

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wks.Protect , UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        'wks.Unprotect
    Next wks

    usrfrm_HC.Show

    End Sub
```

There is one Module1 that is empty

Then I have the following in Module2

```
    Sub displayUserForm()
        usrfrm_HC.Show
    End Sub
```

Then I have a form called: usrfrm_HC  Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub cmd_CloseForm_Click()
        Unload Me
    End Sub
    __________________________________________________________________
    'ties the spin button control to the textbox, shows attempts number
    Private Sub spb_Attempt_Change()
        tbx_Attempt.Value = Me.spb_Attempt.Value
    End Sub
    ___________________________________________________________________
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim cReset As Control
    For Each cReset In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cReset) = "CheckBox" Then
            With cReset
                .Value = "False"
            End With
        End If
    Next cReset

    Dim tReset As Control
    For Each tReset In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(tReset) = "TextBox" Then
            With tReset
                .Text = ""
            End With
         End If
    Next tReset

    With Me
        .tbx_Date.Text = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        .tbx_TNumber.Text = ""
        .tbx_LRate.Text = ""
        .tbx_Attempt.Value = 0
        .spb_Attempt.Value = 0
        .cbx_PType.Text = "Select Type"
        .cbx_PType.List = Array("Value1", "Value2")
        .chk_FA1.Value = False
        .chk_FA2.Value = False
        .chk_FA3.Value = False
        .chk_FMA1.Value = False
        .chk_FMA2.Value = False
        .chk_FMA3.Value = False
        .chk_CMA1.Value = False
        .chk_CMA2.Value = False
        .chk_CMA3.Value = False
        .chk_AMA1.Value = False
        .chk_AMA2.Value = False
        .chk_AMA3.Value = False
        .chk_AMA4.Value = False
        .chk_AA1.Value = False
        .chk_AA2.Value = False
        .chk_AA3.Value = False
    End With

    End Sub
    _______________________________________________________________________
    Private Sub cmd_RecordEntry_Click()

    Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim myFirstBlankRow As Long

    Set MyWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Set MyWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

    With MyWorksheet

        'looks for first blank row
        myFirstBlankRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1

        'ensures mandatory field entered or gives error
        If (Me.tbx_Date.Value <> "") And (Me.tbx_TNumber.Value <> "") And (Me.cbx_PType.Text <> "Select Type") And (Me.tbx_Attempt.Value > 0) And (Me.tbx_LRate.Value <> "") Then

            MyWorksheet.Unprotect

            .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 1) = Me.tbx_Date.Value
            .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 2) = Me.tbx_TNumber.Value
            .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 3) = Me.cbx_PType.Value
            .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 4) = Me.tbx_Attempt.Value
            .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 5) = Me.tbx_LRate.Value

            If Me.chk_FLHSWLink.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 6) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FRHSWLink.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 7) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FTROV.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 8) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FPRV.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 9) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FExtPBox.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 10) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FEMED.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 13) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FLHSCPnl.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 12) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FRHSCPnl.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 11) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FNWW.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 14) = "X"

            If Me.chk_FA1.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 15) = Me.tbx_FA1.Value
            If Me.chk_FA2.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 16) = Me.tbx_FA2.Value
            If Me.chk_FA3.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 17) = Me.tbx_FA3.Value

            If Me.chk_FMDHFthru.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 18) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FMACDCPwrBox.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 19) = "X"
            If Me.chk_FMDnuts.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 20) = "X"

            If Me.chk_FMA1.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 21) = Me.tbx_FMA1.Value
            If Me.chk_FMA2.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 22) = Me.tbx_FMA2.Value
            If Me.chk_FMA3.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 23) = Me.tbx_FMA3.Value

            If Me.chk_CMLHSMframes.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 24) = "X"
            If Me.chk_CMRHSMframes.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 25) = "X"
            If Me.chk_CMLHSMWW.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 26) = "X"
            If Me.chk_CMRHSMWW.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 27) = "X"

            If Me.chk_CMA1.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 28) = Me.tbx_CMA1.Value
            If Me.chk_CMA2.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 29) = Me.tbx_CMA2.Value
            If Me.chk_CMA3.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 30) = Me.tbx_CMA3.Value

            If Me.chk_AMBB.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 31) = "X"
            If Me.chk_AMFthru.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 32) = "X"
            If Me.chk_AMDnuts.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 35) = "X"
            If Me.chk_AMLHSFBrd.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 33) = "X"
            If Me.chk_AMRHSFBrd.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 34) = "X"
            If Me.chk_AMBDoor.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 36) = "X"
            If Me.chk_AMWTBF22.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 37) = "X"
            If Me.chk_AMO2SPnl.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 38) = "X"

            If Me.chk_AMA1.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 39) = Me.tbx_AMA1.Value
            If Me.chk_AMA2.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 40) = Me.tbx_AMA2.Value
            If Me.chk_AMA3.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 41) = Me.tbx_AMA3.Value
            If Me.chk_AMA4.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 42) = Me.tbx_AMA4.Value

            If Me.chk_AA1.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 43) = Me.tbx_AA1.Value
            If Me.chk_AA2.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 44) = Me.tbx_AA2.Value
            If Me.chk_AA3.Value = "True" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 45) = Me.tbx_AA3.Value

            If Me.tbx_Comments.Value <> "" Then .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 46) = Me.tbx_Comments.Value

            MyWorksheet.Protect , UserInterfaceOnly:=True

            'reset color if there had been an error
            Me.lbl_Date.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Me.lbl_AC.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Me.lbl_PType.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Me.lbl_Attempt.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Me.lbl_LRate.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

            'resets form after entry submit
            UserForm_Initialize
        Else
            'displays red error if not filled out correctly
            If (Me.tbx_Date.Text = "") Then Me.lbl_Date.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) Else Me.lbl_Date.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

            If (Me.tbx_TNumber.Text = "") Then Me.lbl_AC.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) Else Me.lbl_AC.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

            If (Me.cbx_PType.Text = "Select Type") Then Me.lbl_PType.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) Else Me.lbl_PType.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

            If (Me.tbx_Attempt.Value = 0) Then Me.lbl_Attempt.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) Else Me.lbl_Attempt.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

            If (Me.tbx_LRate.Text = "") Then Me.lbl_LRate.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) Else Me.lbl_LRate.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With

    End Sub
    ________________________________________________________________________
    'checks the checkboxes if additional locations are added
    Private Sub tbx_AA1_Change()
        chk_AA1.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_AA2_Change()
        chk_AA2.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_AA3_Change()
        chk_AA3.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_AMA1_Change()
        chk_AMA1.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_AMA2_Change()
        chk_AMA2.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_AMA3_Change()
        chk_AMA3.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_AMA4_Change()
        chk_AMA4.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_CMA1_Change()
        chk_CMA1.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_CMA2_Change()
        chk_CMA2.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_CMA3_Change()
        chk_CMA3.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_FMA1_Change()
        chk_FMA1.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_FMA2_Change()
        chk_FMA2.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_FMA3_Change()
        chk_FMA3.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_FA1_Change()
        chk_FA1.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_FA2_Change()
        chk_FA2.Value = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbx_FA3_Change()
        chk_FA3.Value = True
    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure all references to worksheets/ranges are qualified using ThisWorkbook, not using ActiveWorkbook and not missing.  Other than that there are no obvious issues there.  It would be useful to know which line of code raises the error.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll make the changes and see what happens. Once when the user hit debug it froze the computer. The only option was to restart. Haven't hit that button since.

Comment: Made the changes. Can get the file open now. But when the spin button is clicked or when the or the submit button. Still crashes. Same Error. Hitting debug returns a "recommend closing Excel"

Comment: Edited the code to reflect changes.

Comment: Since it only occurs for one user, this is difficult to debug.  You'd need to figure out what is different about their environment compared to the users who are not having problems.